# Nginx : thousands of server_name

Tags: nginx

how can I configure Nginx restrict to thousands of different server_name without creating thousands of external config files or writing a very long server_name line ?

Indeed, I would like Nginx be a reverse-proxy only for server1.com, server2.com, etc...

The best solution for me would be to have a single external config file containing my restricted server_names : server1.com, server2.com, etc...

Is it possible ?

---

Ok, thank you for your answers, it works without reg. expressions. Just a big server_name list as explained by kolbijack.
Thx.

Comment: you should accept kolbijack answer, if it is the one that helped.

Answer (score 20):

You can put the server_name directive in a file all by itself and then just include it from your server block:

```
# example.com.conf
server {
  include /path/to/server_names;
  ...
}

# /path/to/server_names
server_name
  example.com
  domain.com
  foo.com
;
```

The server_names file just needs server_name at the top and ; at the bottom to be a valid directive.

Comment: Beware of latency/lookup delays/RAM usage if you do this.  I've done some testing with large lists (around 5,000 `ServerAlias` directives and up to 16 million `Deny from` directives) in Apache.  5,000 domains produces a measurable but small delay.  When increasing the number, I found the delay started becoming noticeable at around 50,000.  With Apache (and probably also with nginx), the list is held in RAM which meant that with the largest set I tried, I could only start *one* child process within my available RAM.

Comment: @Ladadadada
LOL. I've just checked. Nginx uses 30Mb of RAM for 100 000 domains in the `server_name` directive and respond `Request rate: 36900.6 req/s (0.0 ms/req)`

Comment: 60Mb for 1 000 000 and `Request rate: 34716.8 req/s (0.0 ms/req)`

Comment: That's considerably better than Apache managed, at least with the prefork MPM.  Handy to know.

Answer (score 7):

The `server_name` declaration in your `server {}` block can be a Regular expression, this should allow you to match server_name s within a set pattern.

More information on this can be seen here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot declare my custom domains list in a single regular expression. server_name [zeus.domain.com|poseidon.domain.com|etc...]; It would be too long.

Comment: @fred Can you give an example data set? unless no one domain is like the other at all I'd be fairly confident that a Regex pattern would resolve you issue.

Comment: @Oneiroi: example use case = user generated subdomains. Imagine a software-as-a-service product where each user gets their own subdomain, and you want to use Nginx to route them to different servers. In that case, no one domain is like the other at all.

Comment: @m.stenta ah, fair point. Unless there's some commonality in the subdomains then yeah regex is not going to work. Or you're going to need to tie in the creation of regex derived from the domain itself which imho defeats the purpose.